# How to fix the at-rule or selector expected error

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out why I am having this at-rule or selector expected error. I've been reading the documentation on at-rule, particularly for charset, and I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. I checked for missing semi-colons, improper indentation, etc; but nothing seems to fix the issue.

```
@charset "UTF-8"; 

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 background: #648ded;
 }

body {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color:black;
  }

#input{
  color: black;
  margin: auto;
  }

#inputValue{
  border: 2px solid #1e90ff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: auto;
  }

#submitButton{
  background-color: #1e90ff; 
  border: 2px solid #fffff0;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #6a5acd;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px   #708090;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  }

p{
 color: white;
 }
```

[Where I'm seeing the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9PxP.png)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the CSS you've posted. Where are you seeing that error message?

Comment: @Alohci In Eclipse it shows up at the very end after the last bracket. I've restarted Eclipse numerous times to see if it goes away and it's still there.

Answer (score 0):

Put @charset "UTF-8"; at the TOP of the css file -- as the very first line. Then the error should go away. I can't tell from your css whether or not it's already at the top as I don't know if you just showed the relevant lines or the whole file. But when I moved mine to the top, this "error" or warning went away. I'm using VSCode.

Comment: It is currently at the top of the CSS file. I'm currently showing the entire file. It's a bizarre error, and I cannot figure out why it's there. I was beginning to assume it's Eclipse, but I don't have the error in any of my other projects.